# Python pandas remove rows where multiple conditions are not met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe like this:

```
   id  num
0   1    1
1   2    2
2   3    1
3   4    2
4   1    1
5   2    2
6   3    1
7   4    2
```

The above can be generated with this for testing purposes:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.array([1,2,3,4] * 2,dtype='int32'),
                     'num': np.array([1,2] * 4,dtype='int32')
                    })
```

Now, I want to keep only the rows where a certain condition is met: `id` is not 1 AND `num` is not 1. Essentially I want to remove the rows with index 0 and 4. For my actual dataset its easier to remove the rows I dont want rather than to specify the rows that I do want

I have tried this:

```
test = test[(test['id'] != 1) & (test['num'] != 1)]
```

However, that gives me this:

```
   id  num
1   2    2
3   4    2
5   2    2
7   4    2
```

It seems to have removed all rows where `id` is 1 OR `num` is 1

I've seen a number of other questions where the answer is the one I used above but it doesn't seem to be working out in my case

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you change the boolean condition to be equality and invert the combined boolean conditions by enclosing both in additional parentheses then you get the desired behaviour:

```
In [14]:    
test = test[~((test['id'] == 1) & (test['num'] == 1))]
test

Out[14]:
   id  num
1   2    2
2   3    1
3   4    2
5   2    2
6   3    1
7   4    2
```

I also think your understanding of boolean syntax is incorrect what you want is to `or` the conditions:

```
In [22]:
test = test[(test['id'] != 1) | (test['num'] != 1)]
test

Out[22]:
   id  num
1   2    2
2   3    1
3   4    2
5   2    2
6   3    1
7   4    2
```

If you think about what this means the first condition excludes any row where 'id' is equal to 1 and similarly for the 'num' column:

```
In [24]:
test[test['id'] != 1]

Out[24]:
   id  num
1   2    2
2   3    1
3   4    2
5   2    2
6   3    1
7   4    2

In [25]:
test[test['num'] != 1]

Out[25]:
   id  num
1   2    2
3   4    2
5   2    2
7   4    2
```

So really you wanted to `or` (`|`) the above conditions

Comment: Btw, a little more elegant: `test.query("id != 1 | num != 1")`

Comment: @user3387223 for this example yes but `query` accepts limited syntax, for instance there is no equivalent support for `isin`